# PC-DOS vs MS-DOS vs Windows multilingual text files

Tags: windows, character-encoding, dos, codepages

As far as a I know, in 1987 PC-DOS 3.3 as well as MS-DOS 3.3 were released and they had several code pages (850, 860, 863, 865).

Does it mean that user could write text using Portuguese (cp860) and, say, Nordic (cp865) symbols in one file?

Or it was something like one code page per one operation system. For example, PC-DOS from Portugal had only 860 code page and user could use symbols only from that code page, and PC-DOS from Scandinavia had only 865 code page.

The same question about Windows. Starting from what version it started to support multilingual text documents?

Answer (score 0):

DOS has not really knowledge of code page. They were just ASCII strings (zero or dollar terminated).

Codepage were used mostly for display: changing a code page, it will change how a bytecode is printed on screen.

What you describe here, it is a frequent problem: mixed encoding in one text. If you are old enough, you will remember a lot of such problem in web. The text file has no tag or metadata about the codepage. If you mix it, you will just see the characters according the active codepage. You change the codepage of screen, and you will get a new interpretation of characters.

Comment: Thank you, but maybe you got me wrong. I asked exactly about code pages in PC-DOS. In 1987 it had several ones. And my question is the following: ope operation system had one code page or several? So I could choose what code page use to read file data.

Comment: @NoNameQA No code page is used when reading file data, as this answer tries to explain.

Comment: @NoNameQA: see codepage as "font" with just 256 symbols. The selection of font is on the viewer, not on the text file. In bitmap epoch (so PC-DOS): programs write on a specific location a code (256 symbols), and BIOS/video card translated each symbol into a glyph. You can have only one active. Text mode had no graphs, no mixed modes, etc. Changing the codepage, you just change the bitmap of the font. it is just display.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do anything you want in your own file. It's communicating how to read it to others that would be a problem.

So, no, not really. Using more than one character encoding in a file and calling it a text file would be more trouble than it's worth.

What the setting of an operating system does not have a direct relationship on the contents of a file. Programs that exchange files between systems (such as over the Internet) *might* use an understanding of the source character encoding and a local setting for character encoding and do a lossy transcoding.

Nothing has changed except with the advent of Unicode more than 25 years ago, more scripts than you can imagine are available in one character set.  So, if there is any transcoding to be done, ideally, it would only be to UTF-8.